# mariadb for node.js ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using the following code to establish connection to a MariaDB 10 server:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "local_ip",
  user: "username",
  password: "my_password",
  port: 3307,
  database: "name_of_db",
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('error: ' + err.message);
}
```

The SQL-Server is running on a machine within a local network.
The SQL-User is granted connections from all hosts (%).
I am able to establish a connection with a SQL GUI tool, with exact the same user.

Seems to me like a bug inside the mysql node package, anybody encountered such a problem?

Comment: MySQL default port is 3306. Are you sure you are using 3307?

Comment: Yes, it is mariadb10, they use 3307. The same settings work from the SQL GUI tool.